# Is there a way to tell which OS X processes are using the most power over time?

Tags: macbook-pro, power-management

My Android phone comes installed w/ an app that graphs out power usage of various components over time, so it's clear that the screen is the biggest user, followed by the phone, followed by Facebook etc.

Is there a similar app for the MacBook?  I'm following best practices yet only getting a couple of hours of time out of a new (reconditioned) 2013 Macbook Pro (Mt Lion) with a battery showing only 10 cycles and near max health on it.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Activity Monitor has this feature. It can chart power consumption per process in the Energy tab. You can find it in `/Applications/Utilities/Activity Monitor.app`.

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like the Energy tab is Mavericks only.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to whether there is a similar App for OSX is yes. There are a number of them, but I'd recommend [**Battery Health**](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id490192174?mt=12) which is available for download in the Mac App Store.

It shows cycle count, original mAh vs. current, time remaining on current charge, and processes using the most power over time:

[image]

As to whether your battery is defective is a different question. [As stated by Apple](http://www.apple.com/batteries/notebooks.html), your battery is designed to retain %80 of its original full charge capacity after 1000 cycles. To obtain some helpful diagnostic information (much of same information Battery Health shows):

Open Finder >    > hold down <kbd>option</kbd> > System Information... > Hardware > Power.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I don't think it's defective, just wonder what's eating up the power.  A while back I found that Chrome was a big power user because it liked (likes?) to turn on the discrete GPU even when not doing graphics-intensive processing.  That's the kind of data I'm looking for.